# Detectives vs Nelson: The Chessboard Serial Killer

Tags: strategy, story, knowledge, chess

This is about **Nelson**, a serial killer who, after each murder, leaves a **chess diagram** in the scene of the crime. These chessboards give the detectives the opportunity to decipher where, how and when Nelson will perform again. (Note: you should know [how chess is played](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess) and how chessboard squares are enumerated).

Detectives **Brandon** and **Makeda** are the two agents in charge of these murders. Brandon, who is the superior of Makeda, won’t forget his black hat under any circumstance. There are also 2 things worth noting:

1. *Both detectives are left-handed.*
2. *When investigating a corpse, they like keeping as close as possible to it.*

---

**Scene 1 (26/Jan/2016)**

It is known this was the second victim of Nelson; the remains of the first victim were never found.

The lifeless body of a 19 year-old teenager was found hanging upside-down a tree. Right under the body, detectives found the first diagram and a very particular weapon next to it. Under the diagram there was a note:

> You first, Makeda. Do it the best you can. And remember: *I'm always one step ahead* of you both.

[image: Scene-1]

---

**Scene 2 (27/Feb/2016)**

At the scene, the detectives found an old man’s body, with two shots to the head. Next to the body, there were three bullets; it seems that one of them was never used. The serial killer left this chessboard, with some **g/unpowder** spread all over the pieces. There was a note:

> I love how *weak* my victims are, detectives. That's the beauty behind murdering people.

[image: Scene-2]

---

**Scene 3 (10/Apr/2016)**

Detectives were feeling really agitated. Three murders in less than 3 months. They needed to stop this massacre, so this last chessboard was crucial to find a pattern and predict the next place for a possible crime.

A beautiful, mid-aged woman had her hands and feet tied down, three shots to the chest. She was lying on the grass, and there was no evidence she had been abused. Again, the typical chessboard next to her, with a note:

> You move again, detectives. And know, by the way, I just *broke down your
>   car*. Mine is wrecked as well, but that won't stop me.
>
> Know, by the way, that *while you are reading this note, I am killing
>   my 5th victim!* There I won't leave any chessboards whatsoever. Will
>   you stop me before I kill my 6th victim?

### [image: Scene-3]

Scared of what they just read, they knew there was going to be a 5th victim. 
Having these diagrams and notes, detectives need to find out:

1. **Where** (square) will the detectives find the 5th poor soul?
2. **Where** (square) will Nelson *try* to kill his 6th victim?
3. **When** (day and month) does Nelson *intend* to kill the 6th victim?
4. Can you say anything about **how** (weapon/method) Nelson intends to murder his 5th victim?
5. Nelson said he wouldn't leave any chessboards in Scene 4, but if he did, **what would that chessboard be?**

*(**Note**: the dates indicated for each scene, are the dates for which detectives Brandon and Makeda find a dead body on the scene of the crime. This concides with the date when the next victim is being murdered.)*

---

**Hint 1**

> First, try to determine what role each piece play (i.e. Brandon, Makeda, Nelson and the Victim). You will note there are two extra pieces. Read through all notes carefully, and in particular, the 3rd note will give you a clue of what those 2 excess pieces are.

**Hint 2**

> The number of shots doesn't mean anything - it just adds value to the story. The date of crimes doesn't mean anything either, but they *do* follow a pattern you need to guess.

**Hint 3**

> Detectives suspect that the weapons used to commit the crimes will help them identify *which chess piece* is playing the *role of the serial killer*. As some of you have noticed, I wrote **g/unpowder** instead of **gunpowder**, and this is not casual. By the way, detectives need to know the name of the weapon used in Scene 1. Can you help them?

Comment: "won't forget his black hat under any circumstance": xkcd ref? ;) And by the way, great question.

Comment: Thanks gcampbell! What is xkcd ref? No, it's just a black hat, no tricky words here! :P

Comment: [xkcd](http://xkcd.com): one of the characters is called Black Hat.

Comment: Oh! No, gcampbell. I'm talking about a real black hat, which in turn has something to do with the pieces on the board.

Comment: Added the first hint, to help you a bit.

Comment: Very nice puzzle idea and story framing. It's great to see some "new" creativity on this site and not just endless variants or "5-min-riddles". +1

Comment: Is the spelling of "g/unpowder" intentional ?

Comment: @BmyGuest Probably...

Comment: Probably so, @BmyGuest. In Hint 3 I will make it a bit more explicit.

Comment: @JoseLopez (the tension builds...) :)

Comment: I'm glad to see this puzzle is being received so warmly by the community. Added a hint 3!

Comment: Bit confused by hint 2, for the latter part.. are you saying they have nothing to do with the positions? Presumably the one for scene 3 and scene 4 are the same.

Comment: Are we to assume the dates of the scenes are the dates of the murders, not just when the bodies are discovered?

Comment: Suggestion! The White Knight may not be Nelson, but his victim, since the piece is turned into a corpse (pawn). g/unpowder may refer to G8 (g = G, unpowder = 8 characters, or G8) on the board, where Nelson would be shooting from/observing. His next victim will be Makeda, reading the note, from a contact poison. (While you are reading this note...) Finally, the last chessboard will be the same as the previous, but with a Knight at F3, and no black pieces (except king). White pawn at F6. The detectives never make it out alive.

Comment: @Arth, the dates of the scenes are the dates when detectives Brandon and Makeda find the dead bodies. I'm sorry I didn't make it explicit, I will do it now. For example, in Scene one, 26/Jan/2016 is the date when Brandon and Makeda find the dead body hanging on the tree, and this is also the same date when the third victim dies. Then, on 27/Feb/2016, the third lifeless body is found, and so on.

Comment: @Psychrom That would have been a much better story than what I presented here LOL! But the complexity of the puzzle and the limited time I had to create it didn't let me make up such a sophisticated story. And yes, I think everybody now agrees with me that the Knight is Nelson!

Comment: do any of the details not in a note, bold, or italics matter?

Comment: Which details are in bold?

Comment: @JoseLopez the things like **G/unpowder** and the names of the people

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All questions asked I have answered, with the mate-in-n idea from @RosieF. Whether my answers are correct, I have yet to see.

Pieces:

> White king: Nelson's car
>  White Knight: Nelson
>  White pawn: victim
>  Black king: detectives' car
>  Black queen: Makeda
>  Black bishop: Brandon

Weapons:

> The **F**lail was found when the knight/Nelson was in the 'F' file, and The **G**unpowder was found when the he was in the 'G' file. It seems likly that Nelson's only other weapons are an **A**xe, a (uh, **B**oomerang?) , **C**lub, ... you get the idea.

1.

> The knight is always where the victim will be, so the 5th victim is at **g4**

2.

> The 6th murder will be at **g5** (see Q#5)

3.

> A comment from Jose says the pattern only has to do with the knight's position and the pawn's rank. In the first board the knight's rank, then the pawn's rank make 26, on the 26th day of the year. On the second board, they make 32, and the (26 + 32) 58th day of the year is Feb 27. Adding 43 from the last board *on a leap year* results in Apr 10. If the (Q#5) chessboard is correct, it will happen in 54 days, or **June 3**

4.

> The fifth will have been done with a **gun**, the sixth with another **gun**.

5.

> Reasoning: From the third chessboard: Both kings will be in the same positions as before, because they are broken. Both other black pieces do not move, because they can examine the body from where they are. The pawn will be where the knight was (see Q#1). Looking for mate in five position for Knight... Found! [G5].
>  Moves: 1.) ...Qh1+ 2.) Kg6 Qd5 3.) Kg7 Qxg5+ 4.) Kh8 Be5+ 5.) Kh7 Qg7#
>  [image: Final-Chessboard-Solution]

Comment: So far so good. For number 2, see @RosieF's answer about the mate-in-$n$ problem.

Comment: If you're able to answer from 1 to 3, I'll give you the +100 rep points, since they expire in 2 hours.

Comment: Almost there @ash4fun. But Nelson cannot be in the 4th rank for the last murder. Note that the position of the knight has actually something to do with the number of the victim he is killing. Good point about the kings being broken (they are the cars, as you said). You are ALMOST there, you just need to modify the diagram and answers 2 to 4. For the date, have into account that both the rank of the previous victim (pawn) and the actual position of the Knight (Nelson) are the only pieces to be considered. You just ALMOST got it right, give it another try! I have 4 hours to award the bounty.

Comment: Are you sure your position is mate in 5?

Comment: Hint: observe that in the Scene 1, knight is in the 2nd rank and pawn is in the 6th rank, so....

Comment: @JoseLopez I have supplyed a way that this can be mate-in-5, but I have not brute-forced it to see if there is a faster way. Have you found one?

Comment: The answer you gave was the correct one, congratulations! I brute-forced it when I made the puzzle so that no other solution is possible (the only correct answer is Ng5. The way you calculated the final date is correct, but adding 54 days to the 10th of april gives me the 3rd of June, not the 4th. Can you check it?

Comment: And please, correct your "mating pattern" or annotations since they are wrong :)

Comment: @JoseLopez Thanks for such an excellent puzzle! It was really fun (and sometimes frustrating...in a good way) to work on!

Comment: No, thank YOU @ash4fun for chiming in and reviving the puzzle, since people seemed to have thrown in the towel. I'm happy you all liked it, and I'll try to create some more in the future when I have more time. Good job by the way!

Answer (score 7):

**Black queen:**

> Makeda the detective. @RosieF found that googling Makeda returned the Queen of Sheba. She is left-handed: "greeting the queen with his left hand." (http://emc.eserver.org/1-3/jones.html)

**Black bishop:**

> Brandon the detective. "won't forget his black hat" -- bishops wear hats, and this bishop is on Black's side. He's the queen's superior because he's always a rank above her. Also, the bishop is always on a black square (not sure if this is intended or not.)

**White knight:**

> Nelson the murderer. <del>In scenes 2 and 3, the number of shots the victim is hit with is the number of moves necessary to get from the knight to the pawn.</del> Apparently the number of shots doesn't matter. But @RosieF has pointed out that one of George Washington's horses was called Nelson. (I don't know why I was thinking of Nelson's Column...)
>  (@Jasen:) On each board the position of the knight indicates where the victim will be found on the next.
>  (@Bulldogg6404:) The weapons used tell us which file the serial killer's piece is. flail begins with f (the f file) and gunpowder starts with g (the g file, also works with the wordplay "g/unpowder").

**White pawn:**

> last (dead) victim. "I love how weak my victims are" -- pawns are the weakest piece. 2nd thing worth noting: "the detectives like keeping as close as possible to the corpse". So this must also mean that black queen/bishop are the detectives.

**Black king and white king:**

> The kings are the extra pieces: 3rd note says "I just broke down your car. Mine is wrecked as well, but that won't stop me". In Slavic languages, "car" means "tsar"/"czar", the ruler/emperor. So the kings are the cars, and they're not working, but it apparently doesn't matter. Also, hint 1 "in particular, the 3rd note will give you a clue of what those 2 excess pieces are" implies that it is the kings.

The dates follow a pattern. Still not sure what the pattern is, thinking about it.

---

So:

> 1. Square G4? This would follow the pattern of the knight marking the position of the pawn in the next scene.
>  2. Maybe G5? This would just follow the pattern of the knight moving one square up each time. (Or is it something to do with the white king, in which case it would be H5? Or is it related to the dates?)
>  3. ?
>  4. ?
>  5. ?

Feel free to edit and add stuff.

Comment: You are on the right track right now. Don't forget that, as you discover new things, you'll need to explain how you reached your solutions (giving only the solutions is not valid for an accepted answer)

Comment: I am confident that you are correct about the identities of the victim and detectives. That leaves which piece is the murderer and which two are excess. I believe the killer is the white King because his position in the third chessboard creates a pin on their car, the white Knight (it cannot move, being broken down, but not wrecked, as in being captured and taken off the board).

Comment: Another note, the weapons used tell us which file the serial killer's piece is. flail begins with f (the f file) and gunpowder starts with g (the g file, also works with the wordplay "g/unpowder"). The only piece that stands on those ranks in all three respective scenes is the knight - our serial killer.

Comment: Come on guys, cheer up! This solution contains sufficient information to solve the first 2 questions!

Comment: Why g4? Why g5? Where are kings placed in the final chessboard?

Comment: Answer to question 1 is correct, so is your argument. Answer to question number 2 may or not be correct, the argument is incorrect. Take a look at @RosieF answer below and see if that helps with number 2.

Comment: I think the answer to number 2, is F6. Because that is the position where he would be able to attack blacks king (car). It also leaves his king (car) wrecked by the queen. But he says that won't stop him.

Answer (score 3):

Fascinating! So far, I've noticed that, in scene 1,

> Black to move can #2 by 1... Qf1 2 Kh2 Bc7#

and that in scene 2,

> Black to move can #3 by 1... Qxf2 2 Ne2 Kg8/Kh7 3 N~ Qg1#
>
>  I'm not sure that that's relevant, though: a long-range check goes with a close-combat weapon and a close-range check goes with gunpowder??

and that in scene 3

> Black to move can #4 with 1... Qxg3.

Note that

> these are the 2nd, 3rd and 4th murders. That is, the position left at the scene of the $n$th murder is that of a mate-in-$n$ problem, with Black to move and mate. And with the same material. Perhaps the bQ is Nelson and the bB his sidekick? And the bK the Mr Big who stays away from the action but throws in a waiting-move when needed, as in scene 2's 2nd move by Black? Or am I overthinking this?
>
>  Edited apropos Jose's comment of 20:14Z: Googling Makeda shows that she was the Queen of Sheba (I knew she was called Balqis; hadn't heard of the name Makeda before). So she's the bQ, then? And Brandon the bishop? And Nelson the wK, then? In scene 1, the wK was mated on h2; in scene 2, h1; in scene 3, either e6 or h8. I can't fit that info to the clues, though.

Apropos gcampbell's work

> and Jose's later clues about how Nelson likes how weak his victims are, and how B & M like to keep close to the corpse -- yes, the victim being the wP now makes sense, but that means that in scenes 2 M destroyed the victim, and in scene 3 M destroyed the victim and Nelson.

Another thing that fits in with gcampbell's work is that

> One of George Washington's horses was named [Nelson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelson_%28horse%29).

As to the weapons,

> the first one is a flail. So the first letter of the weapon's name labels the file on which Nelson/wN stands, in the diagram.

Comment: Good observations!

Comment: It took me quite a while to create this puzzle, hope you guys enjoy it

Comment: You are overthinking a bit. The puzzle itself is a bit complicated, so don't worry to get it wrong at first! Each piece plays a role, but I'm not sure you got each role right. Start first trying to determine which piece corresponds to which person. Hint: Mr. Nelson has no sidekick!

Comment: Good job googling that name, that gave you who is the bQ. Since both detectives are in the same team, you should have a clue of who is the other black piece (pay attention to his name). With time, things will start to make sense (anyway I will be adding Hints from time to time, to help people in solving it!)

Comment: @JoseLopez Don't add hints too quickly out of impatience. Good puzzles need time and you don't want to spoil your own fun. IMHO, it's better to have a good puzzle "linger" for a month than to spoil it too quickly by too many hints. Only when you think your puzzle is "dead" you should "revive" it with hints and/or bounties (if nobody else does it already.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, @BmyGuest. I'm afraid, however, people start losing their interest for this puzzle, that's why I like adding hints at least twice a day. But I will stop adding hints for at least 2 days or so!

Comment: @JoseLopez Weekends are worse. (Seems a lot of people puzzle during office hours ;c) ) Some of my puzzles remained "unsolved" for over a month with little action on it. Some people puzzle "silently" for days without letting you know. And some people pick particularly on "old unsolved" puzzles.

Comment: Thanks my friend. I won't be giving more hints for about a week, let's see how people attempt to solve this!

Comment: I agree with @BmyGuest.  Those who are truly interested don't lose interest, they do seem to go dormant for a while though, but that doesn't mean they're gone.  I've been around all weekend but haven't touched the pirate puzzle, I'm still enraptured by it though.

Answer (score 3):

(Edited to take account of a clue whose significance I hadn't previously realised:)

If Nelson did leave a chessboard at the scene of the 5th murder, it might play out like this:

The body of another teenage girl was found high up a tree, close to the scene of the second murder. She had been hacked to death. By the tree were an axe and a chessboard with [this position](http://www.jinchess.com/chessboard/?p=----------------k--bP------q-----------K--------N---------------&tm=b)

> Reasoning: The same material as in the previous diagrams: white king, knight, pawn; black king, queen, bishop. This is pertinent because the chessmen other than the kings represent the characters in the drama, and the set of characters is the same as before. As in the previous diagrams, Black's queen and bishop are on the same file, with the bishop one rank higher than the queen -- perhaps because the bishop represents the superior officer. These black pieces are close to the pawn because "When investigating a corpse, they like keeping as close as possible to it", and the pawn represents the corpse. The previous diagrams solved as "Black to play and mate in $n$" problems with $n=2, 3, 4$ respectively; thus $5$ here.
>
>  The clue "Both detectives are left-handed" has just struck me -- now I guess that bishop and queen should be to the left of the pawn. 
>
>  The problem solves as 1... Qg2 2 Nb4+ Bxb4 3 Kh5 Be7 4 Kh6 Qg8 5 Kh5 Qg5#

Comment: Hey Rosie, thanks for adding your reasoning as @BmyGuest suggested. I upvoted because of your courage in being the first to attach a chessboard. The reasoning is very plausible, and you managed to interpret a lot of the hints the puzzle gives (maybe not all). However, the final position is not what you suggested. Also, the weapon is not right (good attempt though). Finally, you need to answer all of the 5 questions the puzzle asks at the bottom - giving your reasoning for each one! You are on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to another observation by gcampbell, that

> in each scene the pawn is where the knight was in the previous scene. All other reasoning is as before.

If Nelson did leave a chessboard at the scene of the 5th murder, it might play out like this:

> Another body was discovered, a little way above where the previous victim was found. Again there were traces of gunpowder. By the tree was a chessboard with [this position](http://www.jinchess.com/chessboard/?p=------------------k---K---------N----bP------q------------------&dsc=%23999&lsc=%23eee&cm=o)

The problem solves as follows:

> 1... Qxg4 2. Kf6 Kd6 3. N~ Be5+ 4. Kf7 Qg7+ 5. Ke8 Qe8#/Qg8#. If 3. Kf7 then 3... Be5 or Bh6 also leads to mate in 5.
>
>  Unfortunately, if there'll be another murder where Nelson is now, Brandon and Makeda won't ever find the body if they continue to work left-handed.

Comment: Although some of your pieces in the diagram you suggested are OK, it's still incorrect. This is because there is information you are missing. Why did you place kings that way?